# Position Absolute FIREFOX vs CHROME again

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with positioning the button correctly in both Chrome and Firefox. 
In chrome the button goes left, while in Firefox it's where it should be (after the input button)

```
<td style="position: relative;">
<input type="text" id="search_box" value="" style="float: left; width: 160px;" name="search_term">
<input id="term_options_btn" style="z-index: 501; position:absolute;float: left;" type="button" class="client_ac_showall" value="▼" onclick="ShowTermOptions()">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div style="margin-left: 73px; display: none;" class="term_options">
    <div><label><input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" name="search_in_topics">Szukaj w tytule</label></div>
    <div><label><input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" name="search_in_posts">Szukaj w postach</label></div>
</div>
```

here's demo
http://jsfiddle.net/4bZFT/

Comment: `position:absolute` **and** `float:left`? Why are you using both of these?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `position:absolute` from `<input id="term_options_btn".../>` and the button will appear to the right of the text input on both browsers.

[Modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bZFT/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `position:absolute`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/4bZFT/5/.

Answer (score 0):

Just `remove inline style` from button and try this

```
<input id="term_options_btn" type="button" class="client_ac_showall" value="▼" onclick="ShowTermOptions()">
```

**It will display button where it should be in both browser mozilla and chrome.**